# Prolog: Why do I keep getting a operator expected error, how can I fix this?

Tags: prolog, syntax-error, clpfd

[Operator Expected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpiAH.png)

I am new to prolog and trying to understand how to fix this error. This code is where the issue occurs:

```
% Checks if the sum constraint of a cage is met.
sum(S, S, [], _).
sum(SumOfCells, S, [RowIndex-ColIndex|Lt], T) :-
    nth(RowIndex, T, Row), nth(ColIndex, Row, CellVal),
    NewSum #= SumOfCells + CellVal, sum(NewSum, S, Lt, T).
```

"Syntax error: Operator expected".

It is my understanding that I have declared a variable NewSum and am trying to set it equal to the sum of SumOfCells and CellVal. Can you help me identify what I did wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you really using `gnu-prolog`? It is working for me. If you are actually using `swi-prolog` you need to load `library(clpfd)`.

Comment: That screenshot looks like one from `swish` which runs `swi-prolog`.